# Arrow tips on geom_segment in ggplot2 are slightly offset. How do I fix this?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-segment

I am setting up a plotting space for a scatterplot and I am trying to add axes with arrowed tips using the geom_segment function in ggplot2.

This is the code I have so far:

```
Max <- 5;
   xaxis1 <- c(-Max,0);
   xaxis2 <- c(Max,0);
   yaxis1 <- c(0,-Max);
   yaxis2 <- c(0,Max);
 ggplot() +
   coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-Max,Max), ylim = c(-Max,Max)) +
   theme_minimal() +
   scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
   scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
   geom_segment(aes(x = xaxis1, y = yaxis1, xend = xaxis2, yend = yaxis2),
                color = "black",
                linewidth = 1,
                lineend = "round",
                linejoin = "round",
                arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.4, "cm"), ends = "both"))
```

As you can hopefully see from the below image, the arrow tips on the horizontal axis are shifted down slightly and the arrow tips on the vertical axis are shifted right slightly. How can I make the plot so that they are perfectly centered on the line?

[image]

Comment: I suspect this appearance is due to a lack of anti-aliasing with your graphics device. Is this what you're seeing in the Plots window? You might try using `ragg` as your default plot device: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2021/02/modern-text-features/

Comment: FYI, there are probably easier ways than drawing your own axes with lines.  `+ theme(axis.line.y = element_line(arrow = grid::arrow(length = unit(0.3, "cm"), ends = "both")))` for example, will add arrow tips to the standard axis lines I think.

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen I tried that first, but this places the axes at the left and bottom sides of the plot space when I need them in the center at x = 0 and y = 0

Comment: @JonSpring I installed the 'ragg' package and did as the link you shared suggested (change backend to 'AGG' under Global Options>General>Graphics; it was set to 'Default' before) and the arrows are showing up perfectly now! Thank you so much :)